# Split Strings inside a List

Tags: python

I'm trying to split strings inside a list and store it in another list. My code is giving me a "List index out of range" error.

```
line_split = []

for i in range(len(phrase)):
    line_split[i] = phrase[i].split()
    gap = length % len(phrase[i])
```

phrase =
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,', 'consectetur adipiscing elit,', 'sed do eiusmod tempor', 'incididunt ut labore et', 'dolore magna aliqua.']

Comment: `line_split` is an empty list, any index will be too large for it.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `line_split` s an empty list, so even index 0 is out-of-range...
Use `append` instead of indexing as so -

```
line_split.append(phrase[i].split())
```

Also, this can be done with a simple list-comprehension, which is readable and compact:

```
phrase = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,', 'consectetur adipiscing elit,', 'sed do eiusmod tempor', 'incididunt ut labore et', 'dolore magna aliqua.']
line_split = [p.split() for p in phrase]
```

Last but not least - I don't know what "`gap`" is supposed to be, but `length` is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Aswell as appending you can initialize the list with empty values:

```py
line_split = [""] * len(phrase)
```